# value of type '[SKNode ]'has no member 'name'

Tags: swift

I have problem in my code. please help me in line number 5! The error says:

> value of type '[SKNode ]'has no member 'name'

Here's the function where I get the error:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodeITapped = self.nodes(at: pointOfTouch)

        if nodeITapped.name == "startButton"{

            let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)

        }
```

I get error on the line with `if nodeITapped.name == "startButton"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.nodes(at: pointOfTouch)` returns an array of nodes, so you should loop though that array checking each node.  Also, you should `return` from your function after you have found that node:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        for nodeITapped in self.nodes(at: pointOfTouch) {

            if nodeITapped.name == "startButton" {

                let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
                sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
                let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)

                // found the one I was looking for, so don't continue
                return
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a million!! It fixed the problem ❤️

Answer (score 0):

> as you are getting this error: value of type '[SKNode ]'has no member 'name'
>
> > I think nodeITapped is an array of nodes so use like

```
nodeITapped.name.name == "startButton"
```

> **Or**
>
> can try loop like this:

```
for nodeITapped in self.nodes(at: pointOfTouch) {

    if nodeITapped.name == "startButton"{
```

Comment: Thanks a million!! It fixed the problem ❤️